# Changes in Eclipse RCP/RAP from Kepler to Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, rcp, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-oxygen

Hey I'm currently working on a legacy project which is using the *Eclipse Application* environment and the OSGi interface.

I'm not very experiencend in this tech stack, but I achieved to start the program from the Eclipse IDE as mentioned in the exisiting documentation.

The problem is, that the documentation is outdated and still relying on Eclipse Kepler(4.3) to run.

I've tried to use the newest version of Eclipse (Oxygen) and import the project, but the launch process fails on several errors. To dig deeper into the subject, I want to ask you if you know if there are major changes in the environment between Eclipse Kepler and Oxygen. If so, is there any good source or reference to read through or suggestions to begin the research on the whole Eclipse application stack?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually Eclipse Photon (4.8) is the newest version with Eclipse 2018-09 due out next month. The APIs that RCPs use are fairly stable and haven't changed all that much.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Kepler included [RAP 2.1.0](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/rt.rap/releases/2.1.0) and Eclipse Photon includes [RAP 3.5.0](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/rt.rap/releases/3.5.0), so everything relevant for you should be in the [**RAP 3.0 Migration Guide**](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/noteworthy/3.0/migration-guide/).

See also: Eclipse Help - RAP Developer Guide - References (in particular: Javadoc - Deprecated APIs):

- Kepler (4.3) - RAP 2.1.0: [Reference](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/nav/52_5) - [Deprecated API](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.rap.doc/guide/reference/api/deprecated-list.html)
- Luna (4.4) - RAP 2.3.0: [Reference](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/nav/53_5) - [Deprecated API](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.rap.doc/guide/reference/api/deprecated-list.html)
- Mars (4.5) - RAP 3.0.0: [Reference](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/nav/65_5) - [Deprecated API](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.rap.doc/guide/reference/api/deprecated-list.html)
- Neon (4.6) - RAP 3.1.0: [Reference](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/nav/75_5) - [Deprecated API](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.rap.doc/guide/reference/api/deprecated-list.html)
- Oxygen (4.7) - RAP 3.2.0: [Reference](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/nav/87_5) - [Deprecated API](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.rap.doc/guide/reference/api/deprecated-list.html)
- Photon (4.8) - RAP 3.5.0: [Reference](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/nav/87_5) - [Deprecated API](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.rap.doc/guide/reference/api/deprecated-list.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I am looking for. I will work through the migration guide and the documentation and hope to get everything running!